# "Rispetto a" versus "in confronto a"

Tags: word-usage, difference

Quali sono le differenze di uso delle locuzioni "rispetto a" e "in confronto a"? Si possono usare indistintamente in frasi come, per esempio, queste?

> - Penso che ci siano molti vantaggi nel viaggiare in treno **rispetto a** farlo in macchina.
> - Penso che ci siano molti vantaggi nel viaggiare in treno **in confronto a** farlo in macchina.

Answer (score 3):

Sì, puoi usare entrambe le forme, ma è meglio risparmiare parole:

> Penso che ci siano più vantaggi a viaggiare in treno che in macchina
>   Penso che sia molto più vantaggioso viaggiare in treno che in macchina

sono meno prolissi.

Comment: Ancora meno prolisso: penso che sia (molto) meglio viaggiare in treno che in macchina.

Comment: @karoshi Più breve ma anche più generico.

Comment: È vero, però quando si dice que qualcosa è "meglio" o "migliore", generalmente si intende che offre un qualche tipo di vantaggio, che è anch'esso un termine piuttosto generico.