# Sull'uso di "riguardo" versus "rispetto"

Tags: word-usage, difference

Ho un po' di confusione sull'uso di queste parole nel senso di "relazione, rapporto, attinenza...". In [questa domanda](https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/2296/707) si è discusso sulla locuzione "riguardo a" e in un commento (e anche in [questo post](https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/3610/707)) si è menzionato anche la locuzione "rispetto a". Dunque, sarebbe corretta questa frase?

> Ho un dubbio *rispetto all*'uso di questa parola.

So anche dell'esistenza di locuzioni come *a riguardo* o *al riguardo*, che si possono usare in frasi come, per esempio, queste:

> - Potreste dirmi qualcosa *al riguardo*?
> - La luna è molto piccola *a riguardo* della terra (esempio tratto dal [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/riguardo/)).

Sarebbe corretto usare *rispetto* in queste frasi?

> 1. Potreste dirmi qualcosa *al rispetto*?
> 2. La luna è molto piccola *rispetto* della terra.

Potreste aiutarmi a chiarire i miei dubbi?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I due termini non sono perfettamente intercambiabili, *riguardo a X* si usa per indicare il soggetto della frase (un'altra opzione diffusa è *in merito a X* che ha lo stesso uso e significato), mentre *rispetto a X* si usa per esplicitare un termine di paragone.

Di conseguenza

> 1. Potreste dirmi qualcosa al rispetto ?

Questa domanda per molti sarebbe priva di significato (con risposta immediata "rispetto a cosa?" dell'interlocutore, che si aspetta il secondo "soggetto" con cui operare il paragone).

> 1. Potreste dirmi qualcosa al riguardo?

In questo modo la frase diventa una richiesta di ulteriori dettagli sullo stesso soggetto.

> 2. La Luna è molto piccola rispetto alla Terra.

Sarebbe *La Luna è molto piccola a confronto con la Terra* (perfettamente corretta e comprensibile).

Un ultimo esempio mettendo insieme le due frasi diventerebbe

> 3. La Luna è molto piccola rispetto alla Terra. Potreste dirmi qualcosa al riguardo?

Parafrasabile come *La Luna è molto piccola se messa a confronto con la Terra. Potreste dirmi qualcosa che abbia come soggetto la Luna?* ("la Luna" è il soggetto della frase precedente).

Comment: "rispetto" si usa anche in altri sensi , cfr. per esempio http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/rispetto/ al punto 5b.

Comment: “rispetto della terra” dovrebbe essere “rispetto alla terra”. E forse andrebbero usate le maiuscole, perché si parla di *quei* corpi celesti.

Comment: @egreg Nei vari copia-incolla-formatta ho perso per strada delle cose. Corretto!

Answer (score 2):

> Ho un dubbio rispetto all'uso di questa parola.

Questa frase è corretta. Si può anche dire, più semplicemente e comunemente

> Ho un dubbio sull'uso di questa parola.

anche se così, ovviamente, non si usa la parola oggetto della discussione.

Sulle ultime due frasi: la 1. è corretta, mentre per quanto riguarda la 2., la preposizione è "a", quindi puoi dire:

> La luna è molto piccola *rispetto alla* terra.

Comment: Ok, ho vaghi ricordi che "Terra" e "Luna" forse si dovrebbero scrivere con l'iniziale maiuscola, però non è attinente alla domanda.

Comment: Quest'esempio è stato tratto dalla [Treccani]( http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/riguardo/).

Comment: @Charo no, hai copiato male l'esempio dalla treccani:

    la luna è molto piccola >>a<< rispetto della terra

Comment: @Charo parliamo di "rispetto", non di "riguardo" :) Comunque sì, era "a riguardo della ...".

Comment: Semplicemente volevo dire che "luna" e "terra" sono scritte con l'iniziale minuscola nell'esempio della Treccani.

Comment: Ah! Cap problema. Comunque ho trovato: "I nomi dei corpi celesti vanno in maiuscolo (es.: la Terra, la Luna). Le parole terra, luna e sole vanno invece minuscole quando non presentano accezione astronomica (es. come in cielo così in terra, chiaro di luna, giornata di sole)". http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aiuto:Maiuscolo_e_minuscolo. Credo che in questo caso quindi debba essere maiuscola, strano che la Treccani usi la minuscola.